# Arranging business logic in application package

Tags: java, android, coding-style

I am pretty new to Java and currently I am developing my very first Android application using Eclipse + Android SDK. The business logic of my application is stored in "/src/app.package/*". Currently all my files (e.g. activities, adapters, classes, etc.) are stored in the root of "/src/app.package/". This looks a bit confusing to me. I think, sub-folders/packages for activities, adapters, classes, ... would be better and more clearly. Are there any best practices to arrange all the business logic in sub-folders/packages or can everybody do, what he wants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of packages as a directory. If it helps you to be more organized to put all of the adapter classes into the package `com.company.app.adapters` and all the activities in `com.company.app.activities` then go for it. Make it readable/approachable to someone who might be maintaining your code later on down the road.

Comment: OK, thanks. Next time, I should search (with the right keywords) before ask. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472802/how-to-organize-android-source-code-into-folders) I found a similar question :-/